# Progression phase resolution and effectiveness of progression cards

Tags: mundus-novus

I encountered the following situation playing Mundus Novus:

1. The indigenous people event was under effect;
2. A player then used his cards to acquire Juan de la Cosa during the progression step, therefore canceling the effect indigenous people had on him;
3. Then he traded the remaining 5 cards on his hand for the full reward of 7 doubloons, instead of 5 as would be expected since indigenous people was in play.

Did we play this correctly? Progression cards are effective immediately like that? Is there a particular order that players must follow when playing through the progression step?